# libgdx difference between sprite and actor

Tags: sprite, libgdx, actor

I'm just going through the javadoc and various tutorials on libgdx and I'm at the stage of trying to figure out differences between various concepts that seem similar to me or provide similar capabilities in libgdx.

At first I thought scene2d was about creating interactive items such as menus, etc but various tutorials I'm reading use scene2d/actors for the main game items (i.e. the player, etc) and others just use sprites.

What exactly is the difference between using Sprite and Actor (i.e. scene2D) in a game and when should you choose?

Thanks.

Comment: I am facing same confusion right now. Libgdx examples uses sprites, somewhere actor and image as well. Have you figured out how all this goes around?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

A `Sprite` is basically an image with a position, size, and rotation. You draw it using [`SpriteBatch`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/index.html?com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html), and once you have your your `Sprite`s and your `SpriteBatch`, you have a simple, low-level way to get 2D images on the screen anywhere you want. The rest is up to you.

`Actor`, on the other hand, is part of a scene graph. It's higher-level, and there's a lot more that goes into a scene graph than just positioning images. The root of the scene graph is the `Stage`, which is not itself displayed. The `Stage` is a container for the `Actors` that you add to it, and is used for organizing the scene. In particular, input events are passed down through the `Stage` to the appropriate `Actor`, and the `Stage` knows when to tell the `Actor` to draw itself. A touch event, for example, only gets sent to the `Actor` that got touched.

But note that `Actor` does not contain a texture like `Sprite` does. Instead you probably want to use [`Image`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/index.html?com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Image.html), a subclass of `Actor` that's probably closer to `Sprite` than just a plain `Actor`. Other subclasses of `Actor` contain text, and so on.

Another big advantage of `Actor`s is that they can have `Action`s. These are a [big topic](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d#actions), but they essentially allow you to plan a sequence of events for that `Actor` (like fading in, moving, etc) that will then happen on their own once you set them.

So basically `Actor` does a lot more than `Sprite` because it's part of a graphical framework.

Comment: Would you say that Stage and Actor is probably better used for 3D games and Sprite and SpriteBatch better for 2D games?

Comment: No, they're both for 2D. Stage & Actor are part of the scene2d package. Stage actually uses a SpriteBatch to draw its Actors. More info on scene2d here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d

Comment: very nice explanation !

Answer (score 0):

It is more or less matter of taste. If you want to use actions and stage, use actors. Actors cannot be drawn directly, you need to override draw method. Inside draw you can use sprites.

Comment: It's not just a matter of taste. Sprites have limitations that Actors don't. If you want to have an enemy on the screen you create an Actor for that, implement the action "Attack" and can then in your game logic trigger the action with one line of code. With sprites you would need to code the action again and again, in every part of your program that you need it. As well as that the actor and screen are a LOT easier to handle.

Comment: @AreusAstarte That's not true at all. You could (and should) create a class that extends sprite with all the functionality you need.

Comment: That#s not the point. The "matter of taste" is indeed nonsense. As they stand they do different things for different reasons. ANY class can be extended to anything by your logic thus ANY question about functionality can be answerered with "just extend the class" - which would be pretty poor advice when there is something better suited already there in the libraries.

Comment: @RichieHH It isn't the best in all the cases. For instance, sometimes you might need to interrupt action which is already in progress and your game object might end up in some undefined state, between pixels, so to say. Actors functionality is pretty minimal from code amount point of view to not reimplement it by yourself if needed. So, the one should use his common sense and brain to choose.

Comment: @sonofthenortherndarkness : no one said they were the best in all cases. I said "They do different things for different reasons" and then "*when* there is something better suited there in the libraries". So Im not sure what your reply is trying to achieve.  As for "For instance, sometimes you might need to interrupt action which is already in progress and your game object might end up in some undefined state, between pixels, so to say" this is irrelevant to the subject  in hand.

Comment: @RichieHH: No one? I think answer from AreusAstarte tells just that - use actors in all the cases. "Matter of taste" means that you can achieve the same results either using actors or sprites.